# PHP - Google Analytics - minimum requirements for just access to user stats

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

After 3 days trying and trying I'm so confused I decided to ask your help.
I did all the steps from the google tutorials [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php) , I've the credentials, I did install composer but I can't access to my website stats from my web app.Always having errors like per example "Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Psr7\uri_for()", but on the code samples downloaded from google's links Thera are no GuzzleHttp\Psr7 att all, and so on.

The question is:

I just want to access basic stats from my website backend, nothing more, no need to access calendars, emails, nothing but the stats.

What files do I need?

Analytics.php, 
Client.php, 
OAuth2.php, 
Service.php

Anything else?

Maybe I'm getting downvoted here, this may be a stupid question, but I just can't find a solution, or source is out to date, or in tutorials they mention things that are not there anymore.

Thanks, hope tho ear from you

Pluda

Comment: Did you try to retrieve GuzzleHttp library? Try to run: composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle and try again.

Comment: I did install guzzlehttp, some more error came by like this one Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Psr7\uri_for() in . This is an almost infinite loop, we fix one error and we got another one.